# Examples of sets whose cardinalities are $\aleph_{n}$, or any large cardinal. (not assuming GCH)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

One of the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2502/what-are-large-cardinals-for) indicates that large cardinals are useful for destructive testing of set theory. That aside, and not assuming GCH, are there any sets known that have a cardinality of $\aleph_{n}$, $n>0$, or that of any of the large cardinals? There are a few examples of sets that have these cardinalities on [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number), but they are meager and few compared to the examples on the page for [Beth cardinalities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number).

Comment: You cannot prove the existence of large cardinals within ZFC. Not even if you assume GCH.

As for sets whose cardinalities are $\aleph_n$ well, how about all the ordinals whose cardinality is below $\aleph_n$? That is usually enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are very few examples where you directly prove in ZFC that a certain set must have size $\aleph_n$. This is because most of the sets we construct are defined in terms of power sets. This means that we can compute the size of these sets in terms of ℶ numbers pretty easily, but we can't compute them in terms of ℵ numbers. The difficulty is related to the unprovability of the continuum hypothesis. It turns out that ZFC can say very, very little about the cardinalities of ℶ numbers.

One way to get sets of a fixed cardinality is to talk directly about well orderings. For example, $\aleph_1$ is exactly the set of order types of well orderings of $\omega$ (regardless of what $\beth_1$ is).

For large cardinals, there is no way to explicitly compute their cardinality. For example, any inaccessible cardinal number $\kappa$ will have the property that $|\kappa| = \aleph_\kappa$, so you will not be able to make progress by trying to compute its ℵ number.

Comment: I can't seem to make $\beth$ appear. If anyone can, please feel free to edit my post. Thanks,

Comment: interestingly, Math Overflow *does* seem to have it. Perhaps you can post in meta and ask about it?

Comment: One workaround is to write `ℶ<sub>1</sub>` (or `&#x2136;<sub>1</sub>`).